# Find even multiples of a number in a list using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am searching for the most pythonic way to check, whether one or more elements in a list are even multiples of a predefined number with a predefined tolerance. An example is given below:

```
myNumber=3.5
myList=[0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.5,9,9.5]
myTolerance=0.5

myResult=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
```

Any suggestions are very appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by a "tolerance"?

Comment: In other words, for `2*3.5` you'd accept 7 +/- 0.5, for `4*3.5` you'd accept 14 +/- 0.5, etc? (Picking out the corresponding items in `myList` and `myResult` is a little hard on the eyes.)

Comment: As shown in the example. An element is considered as an even multiple, if it only deviates from the "real" even multiple +/- a predefined tolerance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
from numpy import mod, floor
withinTolAbove=[int(mod(number, myNumber) <= myTolerance and
                mod(floor(number / myNumber), 2) == 0) for number in myList]
withinTolBelow=[int(mod(number + myTolerance, myNumber) <= myTolerance and
                mod(floor((number + myTolerance) / myNumber), 2) == 0) for number in myList]
myResult=[max(i1, i2) * int(number > myTolerance) for i1, i2, number in zip(withinTolAbove, withinTolBelow, myList)]
```

The first part determines if the division is within the tolerance of an integer and the second part figures out if this integer is divisible by 2.

Comment: Initially I also thought about sth. like that but it does return the wrong result. It returns [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0] instead of [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]

Comment: Is 0 an even multiple of 3.5? I could add an extra condition to exclude 0 explicitly, but it seems to fit the general definition. How would you like negative numbers handled generally as well?

Comment: Nope... Unfortunately still not the same result as in my example. No, I would say 0 is not an even multiple of the number. Your code so far only allows a positive tolerance but no negative... Negative numbers are not relevant in my canse.

Comment: Yup I just updated to do one search for within tolerance below and a second to search for within tolerance below. I think it works now. modulus the 0 issue.

Comment: Awesome. Just added a small edit to be slightly more pythonic and include the "0 and negative numbers aren't even multiples" condition.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
print print([int(abs(x - round(x / myNumber) * myNumber) <= myTolerance and round(x / myNumber) > 1.5) for x in myList])
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```